# How to send scroll events to parent component when anchored element's are in view React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scroll, jquery-waypoints

I am using React JS [**React-scroll**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scroll) in order to scroll to view certain elements based on Nav click .

But i also want to emit an event when we manually scroll and hit the element

**Update as the question didn't seem Clear**

> By Manually Scrolling and Hitting the element i mean is to manually
>   scroll on the view port and bring the red boxes marked as A, B etc in
>   the stackblitz demo into the view port i:e on the eye line of the user
>   and then emit the event to the parent component which will perform
>   serveral actions

For reference image [image]

in the view port with .without offset so as to set the nav active or perform some actions, i have a custom Impl of Navbar .

I have created [**this Stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/fire-scroll-events) example where i am able to scroll to view but not able to emit events when scrolling manually .. This is a very crud  app to display the use case.

How can we enhance this app to fit in this use case or am i missing something here with the library i am using.

**Update**

I came across a library called react-waypoint which provides this functionality but still the way the waypoint moves out of view is something i cannot figure which does not trigger onLeave event

[**Stackblitz for the trail using react-waypoint**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/fire-scroll-events)

Answer (score -1):

You can set state when user click on Navbar component and if the state is true then you know that user clicked on navbar and you need to perform event else you will emit that event.

your new app component is look as follow

```
class App extends Component {

style = {
"display" : "flex",
"justify-content":"space-evenly",

"overflow":"auto"
}



 constructor() {
 super();
 this.state = {
  name: 'React',
  isClicked: false
 };
}


clickHandler = (a) => {
  this.setState({
     isClicked: true
  },()=>{
  console.log(this.state.isClicked)

scroller.scrollTo(a, {
      duration: 1500,
      delay: 100,
      smooth: true,
      offset: -100
    })
  })


 };

 render() {
  return (
   <div style = {this.style}>
    <div> <Navbar click = {this.clickHandler}/></div>
    <div> <Report isMouseDown={this.state.isClicked}/></div>
   </div>
 );
 }}
```

Comment: @Pradeep. I don't think you got the question, what i am i looking at is how to get that event from the scroll when it hits the element i:e the element anchor in case or react scroll. And then propagate it to the nav to set it. I donot know on how to proceed with getting that event.  Does it make the question clear..

Comment: still your question is not clear.
I ans accordingly what I understand

Comment: I have updated the question and also added image , i hope now it can be visualised . you can also check the stackblitz link